# How do I show what team I am on in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to show what team a player is on under their name tag? This is with scoreboards. I have different ranks on my server with command blocks and i want a player to have a tag under their name that shows their rank.

Comment: @aytimothy While I applaud trying to give users a hint, I'd recommend not even bothering to answer and delete waiting for a timeframe. Just answer in a week, and nobody has to put in moderation efforts to resurface an answer.

Comment: @Frank It's supposed to be a set-and-forget thing; as in: I don't even want anybody to bother with it _unless_ they really want to. Also, the point is to not help the OP but help any future visitors. Though since you brought it up, I guess I'll just undelete it...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do that:

## Via command blocks:

### Differentiate teams by color:

Simply use:

```
/scoreboard teams option <team> color <color>

<team>: command names of teams you've created.
<color> options: black, dark_blue, dark_green, dark_aqua, dark_red, dark_purple, gold, gray, dark_gray, blue, green, aqua, red, light_purple, yellow, white, reset
```

This will appear both in chat and in the player's nametag. Just ensure that the player is in the correct team.

## Via Bukkit/Spigot/whatnot plugins:

[This plugin should do the trick.](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/nametagedit.3836/)

Simply use:

```
/nte player <player> <prefix/suffix> <text>

<player> parameter: The name of the player.
<prefix/suffix> option: Whether to change the prefix or the suffix.
<text> parameter: The text to append in front (if prefix) or after (if suffix) the user's name.
```